# How to draw a dashed line between two cells if a condition is met in Excel

Tags: excel, macros, excel-formula, vba

My Excel file looks like this :

[image]

How would I go about drawing a dashed red line between cell (xxxx) and cell (aaa) if a certain condition is met?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of how to draw a line between two `Range`s and format it e.g. red and dashed. You can adjust the test code to select two `Range`s based on whatever condition is required by your application. Note the test code uses the assumption that `rng1` is on the left and `rng2` is on the right:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    'assume L->R line where rng1 is left and rng2 is right
    'you can set these ranges based on any logic you have
    Set rng1 = Sheet1.Range("B2")
    Set rng2 = Sheet1.Range("G5")

    DrawLineBetweenCells rng1, rng2

End Sub

Sub DrawLineBetweenCells(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range)

    Dim sngBeginX As Single
    Dim sngBeginY As Single
    Dim sngEndX As Single
    Dim sngEndY As Single
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape

    'get worksheet of source range (assume target is same sheet...)
    Set ws = rng1.Parent

    'right middle edge of start cell
    sngBeginX = rng1.Left + rng1.Width
    sngBeginY = rng1.Top + (rng1.Height / 2)

    'left middle edge of end cell
    sngEndX = rng2.Left
    sngEndY = rng2.Top + (rng1.Height / 2)

    'draw line
    Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddLine(sngBeginX, sngBeginY, sngEndX, sngEndY)

    'format line
    shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    shp.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadDiamond
    shp.Line.DashStyle = msoLineDash

End Sub
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting with a formula and format the bottom the border. 
You can't format the inside of a cell, only the outside so keep that in mind.